# SQL InBetween Date/Time Display

Tags: sql, date, datetime, ms-access, timeline

How do I display records from a timeline like people born in between 2008 and 2023 in SQL. I tried many different internet sources but is wasn't satisfactory.

I am trying to make a project for my school and I tried using this;

```
WHERE (((Table1.DOB) Between #1/1/2008# And #12/12/2023#));
```

but it didnt work. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please tag your RDBMS. And what should "it doesn't work" mean? If you want to check for a year between 2000 and 2023, but write between 2008 and 2023, it is no surprise some years are missing.

Comment: A suggestion might be to ,at least, include the full error message (as text, not a screenshot of your ms-access )

Comment: Also 2023 ended on 31st December not the 12th.  Apart from the dates themselves (should be `Between #1/1/2000# And #31/12/2023#`), I see nothing wrong with your syntax.  Is the problem in the rest of your query (not shown).  To help you further, we need the full query you are using, your table structure, some sample data and the exact error message.

Comment: Generally, I doubt it is really correct to set an end of the data range in this use case. Sounds much more like this should just be a check whether people were born 2000 or later.

Comment: @JonasMetzler True! I doubt whether the OP has many pupils who are not born yet, and probably very few who are still babies, but you never know!

Comment: Your syntax is correct for _Access SQL_, but field DOB must be of data type _DateTime_.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using MySQL or SQL Server, use YYYY-MM-DD format like

```
WHERE DOB BETWEEN '2000-01-01' AND '2023-12-31';
```

Or simply use the YEAR function to extract the year to compare.

```
WHERE YEAR(DOB) BETWEEN 2000 AND 2023;
```

**EDIT:**

If you're using MS Access, the syntax is correct, but you're taking the wrong range of data. You're taking data from 1st January 2008 to 12th December 2023.

The date format is in the MM/DD/YYYY or DD/MM/YYYY format, depending on your regional settings. So, use

```
WHERE DOB Between #01/01/2000# And #12/31/2023#;
```

Or

```
WHERE DOB Between #01/01/2000# And #31/12/2023#;
```

Comment: The second query could be very slow because the function YEAR will be executed for every single row of the table.

Comment: Your date format does not work for MS Access!  The format in the question is correct.